# File name variable not recognized by os.Open, but "hard-codded" file name does

Tags: go

As the title says, I'm trying to read a sudoku puzzle file that has 1 9x9 puzzle.  Here's the code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func check(e error){
    if e != nil{
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main(){
    var mFile string
    var puzzle []string

    s := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("Please enter file name: ")
    mFile, _ = s.ReadString('\n')

    fmt.Print("Confirm file: " + mFile)

    readFile, err := os.Open(mFile)

    if err != nil{
        log.Fatalf("Failed to open file: %s", err)
    }

    fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(readFile)
    fileScanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

    for fileScanner.Scan() {
        puzzle = append(puzzle, fileScanner.Text())
    }

    readFile.Close()

    for _, eachLine := range puzzle{
        fmt.Println(eachLine)
    }

}
```

The program asks for a file name, which is accepted and line 24:

```
fmt.Print("Confirm file: " + mFile)
```

Confirms that the file name is captured, but when it passes the variable to os.Open it says that the file doesn't exist.  But if I manually code os.Open("theFileName.txt") , the file is opened and printed as expected.

Any reason the os.Open won't recognize the variable and only the hard-coded file name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also use fmt.Scan() to accept text input from user as long as there is no space between filename (Newlines count as space)

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {

    var puzzle []string

    var fName string
    fmt.Println("Please enter file name: ")
    _, err := fmt.Scan(&fName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Confirm file:" + fName)

    readFile, err := os.Open(fName)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to open file: %s", err)
    }

    fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(readFile)
    fileScanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

    for fileScanner.Scan() {
        puzzle = append(puzzle, fileScanner.Text())
    }

    readFile.Close()

    for _, eachLine := range puzzle {
        fmt.Println(eachLine)
    }

}
```

Comment: This approach sacrifices functionality for "it works" when the answer is as simple as `mFile = mFile[:len(mFile)-1]` or `mFile = strings.TrimSpace(mFile)`

Answer (score 4):

From [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString):

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter.

The new line is in `mFile`. You need to strip that off before passing it to os.Open. When you hard coded the filename, you didn't include that trailing new line.